# VBA Run-time error when closing Excel file?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with a VBA program i've made. Everything works perfect when i open the workbook and make different inputs, but when i close the workbook, i get a Run-time error '1004', with the following message:

> Application-defined or object-defined error

The idea is, a change in the listbox results in a change in the cells D6 and E6. I have a macro that needs to run every time the two cells are changed, which it does perfectly, however i can't close the Worksheet without the Run-time error.

Edit: I managed to make a solution, by including an errorhandler:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Call Sheet1.Worksheet_Change(Sheet1.Range("D6:E6"))
    
ErrorHandler:
    Err.Clear
    
End Sub
```

Comment: @BigBen Absolutely, thank you, i've edited the question

Comment: @ChrisH. The run-time error happens both when i save before closing and when i don't

Answer (score 0):

Are you working on a form or a worksheet?

ListBox is usually an UI Element in some UserForm. Depending on if you set your Form to modal you might run into trouble if your Form is modal and you close the parent worksheet.

EDIT:
Looks like you're not using a UserForm. However, what likely happens is:

```
Call ActiveSheet.Worksheet_Change(ActiveSheet.Range("D6:E6"))
```

Calls your function on the ActiveSheet.If you save or close your Workbook you don't have an active Sheet. For whatever reason VBA probably calls the OnChange Event when you're closing or saving. Try so change to:

```
Call sheet1.Worksheet_Change(sheet1.Range("D6:E6"))
```

You can set the actual name of the worksheet in the VB Editor. You can directly use the name you choose. E.g.: MainSheet can be addressed as: MainSheet.Range(...)

HTH

Comment: I am quite new to VBA in general, so i may have misunderstood your question. But the listbox is an "ActiveX Control" listbox, placed in a worksheet with different input/output cells and figures.

Comment: Hi again. Thanks for the help, it eliminated the previous run-time error, but now i get a different one, i have edited the question

Comment: One caveat. I should have mentioned: There are different ways to adress a worksheet. Either: sheets("sheet1").Range("...) or sheet1.Range(...). The first one applies if you set the name via the table view on the buttom. The latter one is set in the VB-Editor. Although this error isnt very specific, the cause is usually that the code is trying to access things that don't exist.